# Django Define serializer for Model in relation using Foreign Key

Tags: django

I am having 3 models, Site which basically contains Site Details, Comments which contains the the comments and replies to a particular site and Files which contains all the attachments. I wanted to get all the necessary fields from Comments and Files Model, for which I am trying to use a Serializer in Site Details Models. Below is my **models.py** -

```
**Site:** site = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
approver = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="design_site_approver",  blank=True, null=True)
submitter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="design_site_submitter",  blank=True, null=True)

 **Files** site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='site_name')

 **Comment** user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_name_comment')
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
remarks = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='replies')
site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='site_name_comment')
```

My **Serializer.py** file are:

```
**Comment** class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = '__all__'

**Files** class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Files
    fields = '__all__'

  **Site** class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      remarks = CommentSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
attachment = FileSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
class Meta:
    model = Site
    fileds = '__all__'
```

I am unable to get the Values of Files and Comment object, but I am not getting any error as well. What is the solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You should not use "_*all*_" in `SiteSerializer`. Use a list and add all the fields. Also you should consider using `SerializerMethodField` to get the attachments. Something like:

```
class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      remarks = CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
      attachment = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

      class Meta:
          model = Site
          fields = ['remarks', 'attachment'] # + other fields

      def get_attachment(self, obj):
          attachments = Files.objects.filter(site=obj)
          serializer = FileSerializer(attachments, many=True, read_only=True)
          return serializer.data
```